# Grabbing Text from a website using xcode

Tags: iphone

what i am aiming to do is make an app that grabs text from a website and auto updates when the text on the website changes, does anyone have any ideas or any solutions that could help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `Javascript` for taken text you need. Also you can use `NSRegularExpressions` (but it's worse variant). For autoupdating - you should be delegate of UIWebView and check your text in `didFinished…` method.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean an iPhone web app? If so do the following:

```
<head></head><body><?php include ("pathtocontent/content.php") ?></body>
```

And save as e.g. index.**php**

Put in the content.php file:

```
<p>content.</p>
```

Or anything else you want as content.

Then in the iPhone website do the same. Then you only have to update content.php in order to cjhange both the websites

Answer (score 0):

Look at NSURLConnection, send a request to the website, the data will be in the response